"npx thirdweb@latest create --contract " command error "module not found"
PS C:\Users\Dhwanan\Desktop\web3> npx thirdweb@latest create --contract
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './bases/identity.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\multiformats\cjs\src\basics.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\multiformats\basics
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\uint8arrays\cjs\src\util\bases.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\uint8arrays\cjs\src\to-string.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\multihashes\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\cids\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\cid-tool\src\core\base32.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\cid-tool\src\core\index.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\cid-tool\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\@thirdweb-dev\storage\dist\thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.dev.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\@thirdweb-dev\storage\dist\thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.js
- C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\@thirdweb-dev\cli\dist\cli\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dhwanan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\1b718c59dfba7034\node_modules\multiformats\cjs\src\basics.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\multiformats\\cjs\\src\\basics.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\multiformats\\basics',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\uint8arrays\\cjs\\src\\util\\bases.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\uint8arrays\\cjs\\src\\to-string.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\multihashes\\src\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\cids\\src\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\cid-tool\\src\\core\\base32.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\cid-tool\\src\\core\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\cid-tool\\src\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\@thirdweb-dev\\storage\\dist\\thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.dev.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\@thirdweb-dev\\storage\\dist\\thirdweb-dev-storage.cjs.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Dhwanan\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\1b718c59dfba7034\\node_modules\\@thirdweb-dev\\cli\\dist\\cli\\index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.18.0

please help me resolve this error...
